# Python String replace based on chars NOT in RegEx

Tags: python, regex

Is it possible to create a reqex that finds characters that are NOT is a specific set?

Rather than Blacklisting a bunch of characters and replacing them, it would be easier for me to allow a certain set and replace characters that are not in that set.

My set looks like this:
[.a-zA-Z0-9]

I would like to do something like this:

```
clean_filename = re.sub(r'([.a-zA-Z0-9])', "_", filename)
```

obviously this code would replace the characters I want to keep,  is there a way to replace the characters NOT in that set?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Yes, use the `^` negation "modifier": `r'[^.a-zA-Z0-9]'`

Comment: The user could enter ".." as a file name. Would that be ok?

Answer (score 4):

```
clean_filename = re.sub(r'[^.a-zA-Z0-9]', "_", filename)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try with:

```
re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9]', "_", filename)
```