# Python - Validation to ensure input only contains characters A-Z

Tags: python, validation

I'm creating a program in Python 3.x where it asks the user for their first name and then last name and stores these in variables which are then concatenated into one variable:

```
firstName = input("What's your first name? ")
lastName = input("What's your first name? ")
name = firstName + " " + lastName
```

I tried:

```
while True:
    try:
        firstName = input("What's your first name? ")
        lastName = input("What's your first name? ")
        name = firstName + " " + lastName
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("That's invalid, please try again.")
```

which ensures that a string is inputted, but inputting 'bob38', '74' or '][;p/' all count as string values, so these would be accepted, which is not what I want to happen.

I want valid input to only contain the letters A-Z/a-z (both uppercase and lowercase), and if the input contains anything else, an error message is outputted (e.g. 'That's invalid, try again.') and the user is asked the question again. How would I do this?

Comment: this seems to be the way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5183488/python-string-replace-based-on-chars-not-in-regex

Comment: So, Peter O'Hanraha-Hanrahan is forbidden from signing up for your site?

Comment: @DanielRoseman That is a *very* good point....And I, who provided an answer, just realized that my last name would be denied from this site as well. HA! :)

Comment: A [useful link](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/) for thinking about name validation code.

Comment: I did acknowledge that names such as those wouldn't be accepted. xD I didn't mention characters such as apostrophes or dashes because I thought that they would make the solution more difficult to comprehend and complicated, and I'm a beginner in Python (or any programming language for that matter).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you want to do is actually check if your string is not `isalpha()` and output an error and continue your loop until you get a valid entry.

So, to give you an idea, here is a simple example:

```
while True:
    name = input("input name")
    if name.isalpha():
        break
    print("Please enter characters A-Z only")

print(name)
```

Note, that as mentioned in the comments to this question, this is limited to only names that contain letters. There are several valid names that will contain `'` and `-` that should probably be considered when wanting to validate names.

Comment: Or `if  name.isalpha():break` then you don't need the continue, the best solution regardless.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Ah! Of course! Thanks for the heads up. Changed.

Comment: Thanks. Would it be much more difficult to include dashes (-) and apostrophes (')?

Comment: @BobZeBuilder Well, once you start venturing down the path of wanting to validate proper names, you will start realizing that there is more than just characters between `a-z` to validate, and you *might* want to think up something more elegant to validate what a proper name is. You could put together a regex that will validate this.

Comment: @BobZeBuilder If you are just starting out and you are using this to learn. This solution is fine. But it is a good thing to keep in mind, that this solution can get more complex based on what you are trying to validate as a proper name. Keep down the path you are going to learn, but keep this knowledge on the side to visit later. When you get to things like `regex`, you can revisit this and see what you can do to make it more robust. :)

Comment: You could use make a set of valid chars and just check there is no odd char but that would also leave you open to `Mr -----`

Comment: @idjaw Thanks a lot for your helpful advice. Since I am, as you said, a beginner, I'm going to stick to this for now, but I will revisit this in the future to improve it, as you have suggested. Thank you. :)

Comment: @idjaw Hi, I've just noticed something. You didn't put `print("Please enter characters A-Z only")` inside an `else` statement. I believe I understand why - it's because if the name is valid, then it exits the while loop immediately and so the next line doesn't execute. So out of curiosity, would it be less efficient to use `else:` instead of keeping it as it is?

Comment: @BobZeBuilder It's just not necessary based on your correct understanding of what is happening in the code.

Answer (score 3):

There is another solution. It's not as efficient as using `re` or `isalpha` but allows you to *easily* customize the characters you allow:

```
valid_characters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
# Just insert other characters into that string if you want to accept anything else.

while True:
    firstName = input("What's your first name? ")
    if all(char in valid_characters for char in firstName):
        break
    print("That's invalid, please try again.")
```

The `all` checks if all characters from `firstName` are contained in the `valid_characters` string and returns `False` if any of them is not in it.

So to add whitespace  and minus `-` you can alter it slightly:

```
valid_characters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ -'
#                      whitespace is here ------------------------------^
```

Answer (score 2):

`assert all('a'<=letter<='z' or 'A'<= letter <= 'Z' for letter in name)`

This will throw an error if name contains a non alphabet letter.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple regular expression for this -

```
import re
is_valid_name = r'[a-zA-Z]+'

if bool(re.match(firstName, is_valid_name)) and bool(re.match(lastName, is_valid_name)):
   name = firstName + lastName
else:
    print('thats invalid')
```